# metasploit problems

Tags: 14.04, command-line, software-installation, metasploit

I've searched the whole internet for an answer and still haven't found one, I decided to uninstall metasploit i typed in the following

```
$ cd /opt
opt$ ls
google  lol  sublime_text  tor-browser-en  wine-staging metasploit
opt$ cd metasploit
opt/metasploit$ ./uninstall
```

then normally the uninstallation wizard appeared then when i was going to install it again I get this error

```
$ sudo apt-get install metasploit
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
metasploit is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up metasploit (4.5.2-2013031101-1raring0) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/metasploit.postinst: line 20: /opt/metasploit/properties.ini: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package metasploit (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
metasploit
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

so even when i try to start metasploit it won't work

```
  $ sudo service metasploit start
 /etc/init.d/metasploit: 15: exec: /opt/metasploit/ctlscript.sh: not found
```

anyone who has experience can help me solve this?

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to uninstall Metasploit is to first stop the Metasploit service by running `./ctlscript.sh.stop` , and then type `./uninstall` to run the uninstall script from the Metasploit directory.

In your case, you can remove the `/opt/metasploit` completely by:

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/metasploit
```